# C++ int to enum class UB

Tags: c++, c++11, undefined-behavior

I have an `enum` which looks like this:

```cpp
enum class MY_TYPE : int32_t{
    UNKNOWN = 0,
    A = 101,
    B = 102,
    C = 103,
    D = 104,
    E = 105
};
```

I want to cast given values from and to it.

First of all, is it guaranteed that the following code does not induce undefined behavior?

```cpp
int32_t library_func(int* tp){ *tp = 275; return 0;}

int main(){
    MY_TYPE d = static_cast<MY_TYPE>(224);
    library_func(reinterpret_cast<int*>(&d));
    std::cout << "d is " << static_cast<int>(d);
}
```

Is it UB if I cast a value not inside the value range of `MY_TYPE`? About this, I found the following issue: [What happens if you static_cast invalid value to enum class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195312/)

This prints `275` as expected. Do I understand the answer correctly that casting any value which fits in the `enum`'s underlying type is fine?

Comment: For the most part, `reinterpret_cast` is a clear signal that you have UB.  In this case, that signal is correct.  A `MY_TYPE` is not an `int`, so you can not treat it as one.

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33607809/can-an-out-of-range-enum-conversion-produce-a-value-outside-the-underlying-type

Comment: @NathanOliver if it _was_ an int, it would be fine though?

Comment: Another related Q/A: [Why can't C++11 strongly-typed enum be cast to underlying type via pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24566576/why-cant-c11-strongly-typed-enum-be-cast-to-underlying-type-via-pointer)

Comment: @Curunir I believe that is still not allowed, but [this](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.lval#11.2) might mean it is okay.  I'm having trouble trying to figure out what it means.

Comment: @Curunir yes, absolutely. If it **were** an int, you could pass it as a pointer to int, and you'd not have to do any cast.

Comment: @NathanOliver that means that following code is legal: `double* d= reinterpret_cast<double*>(new int); *reintepret_cast<int*>(d) = 12`. Dynamic type of `*d` is `int`, so you can legally reinterpret_cast it to int* and dereference.

Answer (score 6):

Interestingly enough, UB in the example provided is strictly related to the aliasing by pointer, and not assigning enum to value which is not named. If it would not be aliasing by pointer, there would be no UB with using value outside of the enum, i.e. following is A-OK:

```
int32_t library_func(int32_t tp){ return tp * 10;}

int main(){
    MY_TYPE d = static_cast<MY_TYPE>(224);
    MY_TYPE v {library_func(static_cast<int32_t>(d))};

    std::cout << "v is " << static_cast<int32_t>(v);

}
```

Comment: @MooingDuck good point, will rewrite my example w/ int32_t.

Comment: I had already upvoted your answer, but it would be worth adding an explicit note that  `int` and `int32_t` might be different types.

Comment: @MooingDuck actually in this example both would be fine, since it would be non-narrowing.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast<int*>(&d)` would have hit the issue, but you're right that your code doesn't have that issue

Comment: hmm, unfortunately the library function needs an `int32_t*` parameter because it does not only return `void` but some `bool`.

Comment: @Curunir can you add a second (output) integer parameter to the function than?